# Is there any way to control Local Area Permission Dialog on iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, bonjour, ios14

I am using some networking API's such as CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo in order to fetch the SSID. As a result, the Local Area Permission is dialog is shown to the user on iOS 14. If the permission is denied, CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo returns always nil and the application stops functioning.

Is there any way to trigger the dialog again so the permission can be accepted later if the user has accidentally denied it earlier? Or Is there any way to fake the dialog?

Any help/suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can show an alert before calling API's displaying info as to why you need it. If User proceeds with confirmation then can trigger API which shows an actual alert. This way you can show decide to ask permission again.